# Pronoun reference & other enigmas in a poem by H. D. Thoreau

Tags: meaning, pronouns

I'm trying to understand an excerpt from a poem — "Inspiration", by Henry David Thoreau  (see below) — but there are two bits I can't quite get. The first confusing part is the verse "and in my day the sun doth pale his light".

Does "in my day" here roughly mean "now that I am  (or when I become) acutely aware of reality", so not even the sun in all its effulgence shines as brightly? The second puzzle is the use of "they" in the line, "Farther behind than they, farther within".

I'm not sure what the pronoun "they" refers to.  And the whole line itself seems kind of odd — although there's nothing abstruse about the words, the message is not crystal clear : (

Well, to be honest,there are other lines in the rest of the poem whose exact meanings are beyond me, but that's okay; I know poetry is not like math where everything can be accounted for in a step-by-step logical fashion.

Anyway, should anyone be interested in reading the poem in its entirety, see the link at the end of the post.

*The excerpt:*

> I hearing get, who had but ears,
>   And sight, who had but eyes before;
>   I moments live, who lived but years,
>   And truth discern, who knew but learning's lore.
>
> I hear beyond the range of sound,
>   I see beyond the range of sight,
>   New earths and skies and seas around,
>   And in my day the sun doth pale his light.
>
> A clear and ancient harmony
>   Pierces my soul through all its din,
>   As through its utmost melody,—
>   Farther behind than they, farther within.

*The full poem*

Inspiration (H.D.Thoreau)
http://www.the-poets.org/T/thoreau.htm#INSPIRATION_

Comment: It seems to me that _they_ refers to two things: "the din" (that is, the ugly, dissonant, and clashing elements) of Thoreau's soul, and the "utmost melody" (that is, the most beautiful and harmonious elements) of that same soul.

Comment: *"And in my day the sun doth pale his light"* could mean *"I am brighter than the sun."*

Comment: Thoreau has presumably experienced some sort of epiphany and all of his perceptions have changed.  The sun has turned pale by comparison to the "light" of this experience.  ("His light" refers to the sun's light.)  (Kinda sounds like the guy was doing drugs, which is not an impossibility -- a number of his contemporaries used opium.)

Comment: @SvenYargs Thank you, Sven Yargs.  Yes, what you said makes sense, and I believe that's exactly what Thoreau tried to convey.

Comment: @PeterShor    Thank you, Peter Shor.  I agree.  I think Thoreau is referring to a special moment of intense inner radiance which surpasses the sun's light.

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you, Hot Licks.  It does indeed seem like some sort of divine revelation was bestowed upon Thoreau. Although I know precious little about him, I have read some of his work, and my guess is that his enlightenment sprang from sources other than hallucinogens.  I believe it was brought about by an abstemious lifestyle, intense communion with nature and an earnest desire to eliminate all that one can do without and keep only what is truly essential.   Then again, the utopian way I picture him might well be just a figment of my imagination!

Comment: Thoreau was something of an enigma.  Not quite the esthetic that one would be led to believe by reading "Walden".

Comment: Thank you for the cautionary remark, @HotLicks!  Yes, the goody-goody image I have of Thoreau might bear no resemblance at all to truth. He strikes me as having been an honest, upright man, but perhaps this was just a façade or just my own malfunctioning sensors.

Comment: @AbcGiseleXyz - It's not that he was a total phony, or set off to manufacture a "persona" different from what he was.  But, eg, he lived only a short walk from his parents' home and often went there for meals, so he wasn't really "roughing it".

Answer (score 1):

"*They*" seems to me to be a generic or hypothetical crowd from which the poet separates himself in this moment of inspiration. See later the reference to

> It doth expand my privacies
>
> To all, and leave me single **in the crowd**.

"*In my day*"

is IMO

"*In my moments/scenes that are [when compared with the ordinary rest of my [spiritual] existence] suffused/filled with light, so that can be regarded as days*."

The light might mean understanding. His inspiration becomes so strong it overcomes even the conceptual sun of such "*days*," it becomes stronger than plain understanding, carrying him to a higher spiritual plane.

Comment: Thank you, @MariusHancu.  I confess I couldn't quite get what you said and will have to think about it some more.  I'll get back to the topic at some point during the week!

Answer (score 0):

I would think that "they" refers to the "divine electuary" mentioned earlier.

Comment: Did you look up the [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/electuary) of "electuary" before posting this answer?

Comment: I read "electuary" as the anglicized spelling of electuarii, the plural of electuraium, a sweet medicine.